# How to hide implementation details of business objects in a C++ shared library and provide an interface

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, shared-libraries, libraries

I want to have a shared library and pass this library to a few Qt plugins. The Qt plugins work with the library/the interface of the library (Create a few things, edit them etc). **My plan**:

- Start the Qt application and the shared library (The shared library is linked at compile time, so there is no need to use dlopen/LoadLibrary and resolve. The application just has to find the library)
- Search for the Qt plugins and load them
- Pass the shared library to the Qt plugins
- Let the Qt plugins work with the library

The whole Qt thing is clear and does work under Linux, Unix and Windows (With GCC and MSVC). Please **take care about these points**:

- I come from a Java background. In Java there would be an interface, an abstract class that implements the interface and a business class that extends the abstract class. Maybe a factory class for creating business objects and returning the interface to the library user. But the business object is never accessible from outside the class, because it's package protected
- According to information 1: How can I achieve the same with C++ ? My idea was the following (The code for this is at the end):

  - Factory: Create business objects, but returns the interface
  - Interface: Interface with virtual functions
  - Business class: Implements the interface
  - Export the factory and the interface, but hide the business classes
- The solution has to be platform independent
- Link the library at compile time and avoid dlopen/LoadLibrary & resolve
- Make the business objects only accessible over the interface or the factory

This leads to the following **questions**:

1. Why are `dataobject` and `abuseddataobject` **BOTH** accessible ? Why not only the object (interface) created by the factory (And `abuseddataobject` does trigger a compiler error) ? The idea is to hide the business object and make it only accessible via the interface and only creatable by the factory. The library does take care of the GCC `__attributes__` ? What's the mistake/problem ?
2. Is this the common way to do it in C++ or am I "Java-blinded" (See the C++ code) and mix up Java and C++ ?
3. If I am Java blinded, what's the (common) way to do it in C++ (Please with code example) ?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "library/Extern.h"
#include "library/Factory.h"
#include "library/DataInterface.h"
#include "library/Data.h" // NOTE: User abuses our interface and includes the data object

int main(void)
{
    // Create the factory and get an interface object
    Factory factory;
    DataInterface *dataobject = factory.getDataObject();

    // Play around
    std::cout << "Value:" << dataobject->getValue() << std::endl;

    // But now someone abuses our data object ... WHY IS THIS POSSIBLE ?
    Data *abuseddateobject = new Data();
    std::cout << "Abused value:" << abuseddateobject->getValue() << std::endl;

    // Cleanup
    delete dataobject;
    delete abuseddateobject;

    return 0;
}
```

Factory.h

```
#ifndef FACTORY_H
#define FACTORY_H

#include "Extern.h"
#include "DataInterface.h"
#include "Data.h"

class DLL_PUBLIC Factory
{
public:
    DLL_PUBLIC DataInterface *getDataObject();
};
#endif // FACTORY_H
```

Factory.cpp

```
#include "Factory.h"

DataInterface *Factory::getDataObject()
{
    return new Data();
}
```

DataInterface.h

```
#ifndef DATAINTERFACE_H
#define DATAINTERFACE_H

#include "Extern.h"

class DLL_PUBLIC DataInterface
{
public:
    DLL_PUBLIC virtual ~DataInterface() {}        
    DLL_PUBLIC virtual int getValue() = 0;
};
#endif // DATAINTERFACE_H
```

Data.h

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

#include "Extern.h"
#include "DataInterface.h"

class DLL_LOCAL Data : public DataInterface
{
public:
    DLL_LOCAL int getValue()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

#endif // DATA_H
```

And finally the Extern.h. The library build system (CMake) does define BUILDING_DLL for the shared library, so this isn't the problem. At the moment I am just writing a prototype for Linux, so Windows support isn't importent

Extern.h

```
#ifndef SOMECLASSEXTERN_H
#define SOMECLASSEXTERN_H

// Taken from: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

#if defined _WIN32 || defined __CYGWIN__
    #ifdef BUILDING_DLL
        #ifdef __GNUC__
            #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((dllexport))
        #else
            #define DLL_PUBLIC __declspec(dllexport) // Note: actually gcc seems to also supports this syntax.
        #endif
    #else
        #ifdef __GNUC__
            #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((dllimport))
        #else
            #define DLL_PUBLIC __declspec(dllimport) // Note: actually gcc seems to also supports this syntax.
        #endif
    #endif
    #define DLL_LOCAL
#else
    #if __GNUC__ >= 4
        #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
        #define DLL_LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))
    #else
        #define DLL_PUBLIC
        #define DLL_LOCAL
    #endif
#endif

#endif // SOMECLASSEXTERN_H
```

Thank you for taking the time to answer this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell: the `#include "library/Data.h"` should fail to compile.

The `Data` class is an implementation detail of the library. It should never be provided to the users! You should separate the *interface* and *implementation* header files, say in separate folders, and set up the build so that the users of the library don't get access to the implementation files. Just because it's a header file doesn't mean it's part of the interface!

Nitpicks: I presume you agree that you should be using C++, not some bastardized C/C++ abomination. Thus:

1. I suggest using smart pointers, such as `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr`. Every instance of `delete foo` should be viewed with suspicion, unless it's an implementation detail. The compiler takes care of the tail end of [`RAII`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) - use it.
2. It is questionable whether your `Factory` class should be instantiable. Probably you should make it a class with static members only, or even a static member in the interface class proper. The factory function could take the desired type as an argument, if you'll have multiple types that can be built.
3. The `(void)` argument declaration belongs in C only and has *absolutely positively no place in C++*. This is because in `C`, the following are equivalent and different from `void foo(void)`:

   ```
   void foo();
   void foo(...);
   ```

   This is **not the case** in C++!

Your `main` could then look as follows:

```cpp
int main()
{
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    QScopedPointer<DataInterface> data1 = DataInterface::create("Data");

    out << "Value:" << data1->value() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Something I don't understand: If the user has access to the interface header, he has also access to the implementation header (For example a debian package: libfoo and libfoo-dev). How can I avoid the _stupidity_ or _maliciousness_ of a developer to include the implementation header (Because the devel package provides both headers) ? Is this just something I have to deal with or are there good ways to avoid something ?

Comment: @Albertus: libfoo-dev is **not supposed to give implementation headers out!**. If it does, it is **always** a bug. The implementation headers are part of the source code used to build the library, and should never be installed as part of `libfoo-dev`! For example, no sane install of Qt "dev" package includes the private headers (there's tons of those!).

Comment: @Albertus: Those implementation headers are not necessary **at all** to use the library, and would serve no purpose whatsoever. If your implementation correctly utilizes the [PIMPL](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer) idiom, the implementation headers will not expose any private implementation details anyway, so they would provide no benefit whatsoever to the user.

Comment: @Albertus: You must understand, though: the C++ language features are not there to directly protect you from **malicious use** of your code. The user can always use all that C/C++ provides them with to cast the pointers and do "nefarious" things with the instance you provided to them. There's nothing you can do about it on the library side of things.

Comment: Ok, this was the point I missed/misunderstood & you pointed it out. Answer accepted
PS: Wow..the Qt (smart) pointers are awesome, why did I miss it so long ?

Comment: @Albertus: C++ smart pointers have been around for quite long (in Qt and in the boost library before they became standard in C++11). I really suggest you should get *The C++ Programming Language, 4th edition* by Strostrup and see what you've been missing out on. The modern C++ is **nothing like** Java.

Comment: Ok, I will. Maybe it's also a good idea because my Java-background (Misuse of Java patterns/ideas in C++)